# Should I use WHERE to evaluate a field that I am going to set anyway?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Which is better in MySql:

```
UPDATE `table` SET value = 0 WHERE id = 1 AND value != 0;
```

or

```
UPDATE `table` SET value = 0 WHERE id = 1;
```

The `value` for that `id` needs to be zero, but may already be zero. Is it more efficient to evaluate whether it is zero or not first, thus possibly preventing the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL won't update the row if you are setting it to a value it already has. That's why "rows affected" might return zero, even if your condition on `id` found a row. A row isn't "affected" if your update doesn't cause any net difference in the values.

The efficiency of a query depends mostly on selecting the minimal set of matching rows. In your case you're already selecting by the primary key `id` (I assume this is a primary key). That's about as efficient as you can hope to make it.

So you do a lookup by primary key, which is guaranteed to find either 1 row or zero rows (the latter if there is no row with that PK value).

Evaluating the second term of your WHERE clause against at most one single row is not a significant overhead compared to the PK lookup itself.

The difference, if any, is so small that you should probably spend your time optimizing other queries before turning your attention to micro-optimizations like this.

Comment: Good point regarding the primary key. This makes sense, thanks.